# Random delay setTimeout in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

When I execute this code

```js
let object = {
  "Name": "Noah",
  "Gender": "Male"
}

for (let item in object) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(item)
  }, Math.random() * 100)
}
```

I get sometimes

```
Gender
Name
```

I was expecting

```
Name
Gender
```

I have looked into closures but I still can not find anything thats helps.

Comment: Since you're setting random delays, sometimes the delay for the first item will be longer than the delay for the second item.

Comment: Maybe you forgot that all the timers start immediately. `setTimeout()` doesn't wait for the timer to complete.

Comment: What do you expect to see if you're `console.log`ging things randomly?

Comment: `let object = {
  "Name": "Noah",
  "Gender": "Male"
};

let lastIndex = 0;
for (let item in object) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(Object.keys(object)[lastIndex]);
    lastIndex++;
  }, Math.random() * 100)
}`

Comment: @noah, note that "A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an **arbitrary order**" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Thus more safe solution is using an array instead of an object (for example, some code minification tools can break your object properties order).